# Granting calendar api access of corporate gmail account to a third party?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

Lets say company A has a corporate gmail account set up.

Company B needs access to the calendar events (primarily free busy times) of users of Company A via the google calendar REST API.

I see some methods described here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ on setting up api access.

But its not clear which is the best method to go about doing this..Can someone describe a high level overview of how this can be achieved ? I am familiar with the google calendar api documentation and the pre-requisites required to enable calendar REST API...What is not clear is how to apply that to the described scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can update [ACLs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl) of all calendar users in A to allow everyone from domain B to see free-busy information:

```
  "scope": {
    "type": domain,
    "value": B
  },
  "role": freeBusyReader
```

There is a [help-center article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en) about this.